# natbib: Working Paper and DOI in Bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I am having two problems in Bibliography. First, when I cite some working paper, complete information of working paper is not shown and only following information is displayed.

Schwarcz, S. L. (2008). Systemic Risk.

However, the information about publisher, working paper series and url are available in the bib file. 
Second, DOI and URL of references are not displayed in the bibliography. 
A minimal working example is given below:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
   \usepackage{authblk}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{times}
   \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage[round,nonamebreak]{natbib}

   \begin{document}
    \author{Ahmed Arif}
    \title{A Book}

   \chapter{Introduction}
   This is introduction chapter \citep{Schwarcz2008}. The literature is        cited here \citet{Cebenoyan2004}.

   \bibliographystyle{apa}
   \bibliography{library}
   \end{document}
```

The entries availabe in the bib file are given below. The bib file is obtained from mendley.

```
    @article{Cebenoyan2004,
    author = {Cebenoyan, A.Sinan and Strahan, Philip E},
    doi = {10.1016/S0378-4266(02)00391-6},
    file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ahmed Arif/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Cebenoyan, Strahan - 2004 - Risk management, capital structure and lending at banks.pdf:pdf},
    issn = {03784266},
    journal = {Journal of Banking {\&} Finance},
    keywords = {7 december 2001,at the x international,bank risk management,banking and finance held,in rome on 5,loan sales,this paper was presented,tor vergata conference on},
    month = {jan},
    number = {1},
    pages = {19--43},
    title = {{Risk management, capital structure and lending at banks}},
    url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0378426602003916},
    volume = {28},
    year = {2004}
    }
    @unpublished{Schwarcz2008,
    address = {Durham},
    author = {Schwarcz, Steven L.},
    file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ahmed Arif/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Schwarcz - 2008 - Systemic Risk.pdf:pdf},
    institution = {Duke Law School},
    pages = {193--249},
    series = {Research Paper Series},
    title = {{Systemic Risk}},
    url = {http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract{\_}id=1008326},
    year = {2008}
    }
```